# Problemas con redirección

Tags: php

Tengo un problema en donde al poner el direccionamiento de mi sesion en php no lo realiza, solamente carga la pagina y a pesar de que ya comprobé que me mandara los datos correctos no lo hace.

```
<?php
    include_once 'database.php';

    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['cerrar_sesion'])) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['rol'])) {
        switch ($_SESSION['rol']) {
            case 0:
                header('location: menu.php');
            break;

            case 1:
                header('location: menu.php');
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['matricula']) && isset($_POST['contra'])){
        $matricula = $_POST['matricula'];
        $contra = $_POST['contra'];

        $db = new Database();
        $query = $db -> connect() -> prepare('SELECT *FROM usuarios WHERE matricula = :matricula');
        $query -> execute(['matricula' => $matricula]);

        $row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if ($row == true) {
            if (password_verify($contra, $row[6])) {
                $rol = $row[7];
                $_SESSION['tipo'] = $rol;

                switch ($row[7]) {
                    case 0:
                        header('location: usuario.php');
                    break;

                    case 1:
                        header('location: menu.php');
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo 'El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos';
        }
    }

?>
```

**ORDEN DE CARPETAS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba colocando `session_start();` arriba del `include_once`. Sino comprueba con `var_dump($_SESSION['rol'])` `die();`, si retorna el dato para redireccionar.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que debe hacer, qué es lo que hace?